# some details questions about doob's maximal inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, proof-explanation, martingales

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Q1**

I was so confused about this *maximal sequence*, I thought it was a constant random variable sequence at first, but then I realised it should be an increasing sequence (**not really sure**). Then I have a question about this, how could you guarantee the existence of such a sequence? I could convince myself that some terms $M_p>M_q$ for $0<p,q<n$ for some $\omega\in\Omega$, how could you define one term of $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is greater than another for all $\omega\in\Omega$?

**Q2**

I don't quite get the final inequality, I know $E(M_n\mathbf{1}_{\{M_n\geq\alpha\}})\leq E(M_n)$ holds, and I proposed $E(M_n\mathbf{1}_{\{M^*_n\geq\alpha\}})\leq E(M_n\mathbf{1}_{\{M_n\geq\alpha\}})$, but I don't know how to prove this.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Q1 was answered in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523222/maximal-sequence-definition-in-submartingale-explanation/4523231#4523231).

For Q2, this is just because $(M_n)$ is non-negative.  Therefore $M_n 1_{M_n^* \ge \alpha} \le M_n$ - they're obviously equal if $M_n^* \ge \alpha$, and if $M_n^* < \alpha$, the LHS is $0$, which is automatically less than or equal to $M_n$.  Then we just take expected value of both sides to get $\mathbb{E}[M_n 1_{M_n^* \ge \alpha}] \le \mathbb{E}[M_n]$,

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. I am more curious about the relationship between $E(M_n\mathbf{1}_{M^*_n\geq \alpha})$ and $E(M_n\mathbf{1}_{M_n\geq \alpha})$

Comment: Since $M_n \ge \alpha$ implies $M_n^* \ge \alpha$, we have $M_n 1_{M_n^* \ge \alpha} \ge M_n 1_{M_n \ge \alpha}$, with the same inequality holding for their expected value

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking another way around, since $\{w:M^*_n(w)\geq\alpha\}\subset \{w:M_n(w)\geq\alpha\}$. I agree with your first implication, but I don't see how $M_n\mathbb{1}_{M^*_n\geq\alpha}\geq M_n\mathbb{1}_{M_n\geq\alpha}$. You may also write $\mathbb{1}_{M^*_n\geq\alpha}\leq\mathbb{1}_{M^*_n\geq\alpha}$ and then times $M_n$ on both side get different inequality. Much appreciate if you could enlighten me a bit more.

Comment: It's the other way around: $\{\omega : M_n(\omega) \ge \alpha\} \subset \{\omega : M_n^*(\omega) \ge \alpha\}$ because you know that if $M_n(\omega) \ge \alpha$ then you also have $M_n^*(\omega) \ge \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, you are right, it should be $\{w:M_n(w)\alpha\}\subset\{w:M^*_n(w)\alpha\}$, and I would like to know more details about how do I infer $M_n\mathbf{1}_{M^*_n\geq \alpha}\geq M_n\mathbf{1}_{M_n\geq\alpha}$, my intuition told me this is true, but I would like to know the exact step. moreover, I can imagine $M_n\mathbf{1}_{M_n\geq \alpha}$ but cannot this $M_n\mathbf{1}_{M^*_n\geq \alpha}$

Comment: In this set notation$\{w:M^*_n(w)\geq\alpha\}$, does the property $M^*_n(w)\geq\alpha$, this $M^*_n$ may not be the same function?

Comment: I don't know what you mean in your second question, but the fact that $\{M_n(\omega) \ge \alpha\} \subset \{\omega : M_n^*(\omega) \ge \alpha\}$ implies $1_{M_n \ge \alpha} \le 1_{M_n^* \ge \alpha}$.  This is almost the exact same reasoning as the original answer - either $M_n^* \ge \alpha$ and the RHS is 1, or $M_n^* < \alpha$ and both sides are 0.  Then, because $M_n \ge 0$, we just multiply both sides by $M_n$ to conclude $M_n1_{M_n \ge \alpha} \le M_n1_{M_n^* \ge \alpha}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For my second question, simple analogues would be $\{X=3\}=\{w:X(x)=3\}$. There the function $X(w)$ is the same for every $w$ in the set. In contrast to the set $\{w:M^*_n(w)\geq\alpha\}$, here the function $M^*_n(w)$ seems to be different to different $w$. Sorry for this tedious question, I am trying to figure out every detail to make sure I truly understand its meaning. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Yes, $M_n^*(\omega)$ potentially takes on different values for different $\omega$ in the set $\{\omega : M_n^*(\omgea) \ge \alpha\}$, but all those different values it takes on will be at least $\alpha$.  It would be better to ask these as separate questions instead of in the comments, though.