# maximal sequence definition in submartingale explanation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, analysis, proof-explanation

let $(M_n)_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ be a nonnegative submartingale with repect to the filtration $(\mathscr{F_n})_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$.

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $$M^*_n(w):=\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}M_k(w)\,\,\,\,\forall w\in\Omega$$

$(M_n^*)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is called the maximal sequence associated with $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

---

This is exactly word by word definition my lecturer gave us in the class. when I retrieve it repeatedly, I am still confused about how to interpret it.

I've post the question in capture before but nobody reply, this time I leave my thought and if you know the answer please just leave some comments.

**FIRST THOUGHT**

I make some examples to illustrate my first interpretation:

$$M_1^*(w)=M_1(w)\\
M^*_2(w):=\max\{M_1(w),M_2(w)\}\\
M^*_3(w):=\max\{M_1(w),M_2(w),M_3(w)\}$$

If I interpret it in this way I am confused that what guarantees the $M^*_3(w):=\max\{M_1(w),M_2(w),M_3(w)\}$ , one of $M_1(w),M_2(w),M_3(w)$ will greater than the other two for all $w\in\Omega$?

**SECOND THOUGHT**

$$M^*_n(w):=\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}M_k(w)\,\,\,\,\forall w\in\Omega$$ Fixing $n$，we are finding the maximal value of $M_n$ can reach from all $w$, here $k$ is indicating for different value of $M_n$, generated from distinct $w$ rather than it is indicating a different period random variable $M_i$ . If I think through this way, then $M^*_n$ is a constant for each $n$.

I am not sure which way is correct, and if so, please let me know why the other interpretation is wrong.

Genuinely thank you for your help

Comment: There is no probability theory involved here. You are just asking what the maximum of $n$ real numbers means.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your reply. I don't see how this is the same as the maximum of $n$ real numbers. Please don't just downvote and bear with me. When it said for all $w\in\Omega$, I am confused. Is my second thought the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just confused by the phrase "for all $\omega \in \Omega$".  It is just saying that, for each individual $\omega \in \Omega$, we let $M_n^*(\omega)$ be the largest of the values $M_1(\omega),M_2(\omega),...,M_n(\omega)$.  It's the running max of the process $M$, i.e. the largest value that $M$ has reached up until time $n$ on this specific trajectory $\omega$.

Comment: So what is this for all $\omega\in\Omega$really matter? I was thinking this condition needs to be held for all $w\in\Omega$at once.

Comment: @LJNG It's just emphasizing that this is the definition for every $\omega \in \Omega$.  It's not really necessary, but could be useful if it had some other definition in some special cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If you don't mind, would you please check out this **Q2** about maximal inequality.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522060/some-details-questions-about-doobs-maximal-inequality